# What is the free product with amalgamation with the trivial group?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, group-extensions, free-product

I am working on algebraic topology. I am trying to prove the Wirtinger presentation using the Van Kampen theorem.

However, I have some difficulties understanding the concept of free product with amalgamation.
I read that :

> Let $G_1 = \langle R_{G_1} \mid S_{G_1} \rangle$ and $G_2 = \langle R_{G_2} \mid S_{G_2} \rangle$ be presentations of $G_1$ et $G_2$. Assume we have $\Phi : G \rightarrow G_1$ et $\Psi : G \rightarrow G_2$ injective homomorphisms.
> \Then a presentation of the free product of $G_1$ with $G_2$ over $G$ is : $$\langle R_{G_1} \cup R_{G_2} \mid S_{G_1} \cup S_{G_2} \cup [\forall x \in G, \Phi(x) = \Psi(x)]    \rangle.$$

But what happens when we have no such injective homomorphism?

**Here is my problem : what is $\langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle \star_{\langle x_1, ..., x_n \mid R_+, R_- \rangle} \{1\}$ equal to ?**

I assume (intuitively) that it is $\langle x_1, ..., x_n \mid R_+, R_- \rangle$, but how to prove it, since $\langle x_1, ..., x_n \mid R_+, R_- \rangle$ afford no injective homomorphism in $\{1\}$ ?

Thank you very much.

AF

Comment: I'm not sure your object is well defined as it is written - what homomorphism are you using for $\langle x_1, ..., x_n \mid R_+, R_- \rangle \to \langle x_1, ..., x_n \rangle$? The one sending a generator to itself isn't well defined, since the relations won't necessarily map to the identity.

Comment: On the other hand note that you can also define $\langle R_{G_1} \cup R_{G_2} \mid S_{G_1} \cup S_{G_2} \cup [\forall x \in G, \Phi(x) = \Psi(x)]    \rangle$ with homomorphisms that aren't injective, so for instance if $G_2 = \{1\}$ then you get  $\langle R_{G_1}  \mid S_{G_1} \cup [\forall x \in G, \Phi(x) = 1]    \rangle$.

Comment: The idea of a free product with amalgamation is that you have two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ that have a common subgroup $G$ (that is, they both have a subgroup isomorphic to $G$) and you want to construct a group $K$ that will contain $G_1$ and $G_2$ as subgroups in such a way that $G_1\cap G_2=G$. What you write cannot possibly satisfy that, as $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\mid R_+,R_{-}\rangle$ is not a subgroup of either the trivial group or the free group. (cont)

Comment: (cont) You can generalize the idea and consider a group $G$, and two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ that contain *images* of $G$ (homomorphic images); you can then try to construct the most general group that contains images of $G_1$ and $G_2$ as subgroups in such a way that their intersection will "match up" exactly along the images of $G$ they both contain. But in what you write you do not have that setup. If you do $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\mid R_+,R_{-}\rangle *_{x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle} \{1\}$, then you get the trivial group, because you force all the $x_i$ to agree with $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amalgamated free product is a pushout in the category of groups.

Given (any) two group maps $f : G \to G_1, g : G \to G_2$, the amalgamated product $G_1 *_{G} G_2$ is a group with arrows $G_1 \to G_1 *_{G} G_2$ and $G_2 \to G_1 *_{G} G_2$ such that this triple is universal with respect to the property that

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G_1 *_G G_2 @<<< G_2\\
@AAA @AAA\\
G_1 @<<< G
\end{CD}
is commutative.

It can be described internally as :

$G_1 *_G G_2 = G_1 * G_2/<f(a)g(a)^{-1} : a \in G>$ with the arrows from $G_1$ and $G_2$ being the canonical "embeddings".

In your question, there is no canonical map from $<a_1,..,a_n | R_+, R_->$ to $<a_1,..,a_n>$. The former is a quotient of the latter. You must specify the map first before forming the product.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters, not `<` and `>`. The latter are typeset as operators, so the spacing is all wrong when you use them as delimiters. Compare $<a_1,\ldots,a_n>$ with $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$.

Comment: What you write is inaccurate. It is not true that $G_1*_GG_2$ can be "described internally as $G_1*G_2/\langle f(a)g(a)^{-1}:a\in G\rangle$", because the subgroup $\langle f(a)g(a)^{-1}\in G\rangle$ is not normal (unless $G_1$ or $G_2$ are trivial). You need to take the normal closure of that subgroup to take the quotient.

Comment: Yeah I indicated that only. For instance, when one takes a quotient of the space $[0,1]$ by identifying $0$ and $1$, one writes the quotient as $X/0 \sim 1$, when what actually means is the equivalence closure of $0 \sim 1$. Here, $<...>$ indicates Normal closure. This much should be clear since the discussion is on group quotients.

Comment: Again, you should not use `<` and `>`; that's the wrong symbol. And it can't both mean "normal closure" and "(sub)group generated"... as it must when you use it for $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ and $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\mid R_+,R_{-}\rangle$. In that context, "$\langle\ldots\rangle$ means normal closure" is nonsensical. So you should indicate normal closure the standard way.